# Is $\text{rank} (A^*A)=\text{rank}(A)$ for all nonsquare matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

If $A$ is a $m\times n$ type matrix with $m\geq n$ then
$$
\mathrm{rank}(A^*A)=\mathrm{rank} (A).
$$
Is maybe also true in general that
$$
\mathrm{rank}(AA^*)=\mathrm{rank}(A) ?
$$
Thanks

Edit.

My question is different from the question about $\mathrm{rank}(A^TA)=\mathrm{rank}(A)$, because this concerns complex conjugate transposed matrix instead of transpose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if $*$ is the transpose operation, then yes. here is why. we can show that $$Ax = 0 \, \text{iff}  \,  A^T Ax = 0. \tag 1$$ this is true because $$0 = |Ax|^2 = (Ax)^TAx = x^T(A^T A) x. $$

then $(1)$ implies $$N(A) = N(A^T A)$$ together will the nullity theorem $$\dim N(A) + rank(A) = n$$ should give you $$rank(A) = rank(A^T A). $$